# <div> with a sloped edge and box-shadow

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

How can I create the following mock-up in HTML and CSS?

[image: <div> with sloped edge]

I have tried adding a separated `<div>` to create the sloped edge using `transform: rotate();` with no luck.

Mainly, what I want to achieve is:

- Two `<div>` elements with content
- The two `<div>` elements have sloped edges and shadows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `skew` transformation can create the slope, but unfortunately it applies to the whole div, not just one edge of it. You can use overlapping or nested divs to mix straight and skewed edges on the same box - however, this makes the shadows a bit problematic (see http://jsfiddle.net/z9am39sp/).

Another weakness is that with this particular setup, you can't fit the text to the skewed shape.

Still, it may be close enough for your purposes. Your call.

Answer (score 2):

I gave it a shot and [here is my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/cz5de81k/1/).

I used CSS3 transform: skew on a pseudo element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slope">content 2</div>
    <div class="slope">content 1
        <br/>text</div>
    <div class="slope">content 3
        <br/>text
        <br/>text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: #ddd;
}
.container {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    padding: 0 3px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slope {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
.slope:before {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 26px);
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transform: skew(0deg, 2deg);
}
.slope:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.slope:last-of-type:before {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: calc(0% + 26px);
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Notes:

- You might need to play with the `transform: skew(Ndeg)` and `height: calc(100% +
  Npx)` depending on the size of the divs
- You might also need vendor prefixes
- Not sure about responsiveness but according to my tests, it works
  fine.

Comment: That's very smart! I haven't thought of that

Comment: @kiraken thanks! This is the first time I used the CSS3 skew property and boy it is hard :) I decided to add calculations and percentages since it seems that the OP want's it to be as responsive as possible, though keeping that in mind, I chose to skew it to 1deg only since it would give the best compatibility for long divs. If there is a better calculation for the skew degrees, I do not know :)

Comment: From what i know the support for the calc function isn't that good. So i suggest the OP refrain from using that. But aside from this, i encourage him to select your answer. Unfortunately mine was not responsive

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` selectors. You can read more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Also here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhqpt5of/)

Feel free to leave a comment if you have any other question.

HTML

```
<div class="div-1"> </div>
<div class="div-2"> </div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:#ccc;
}
.div-1{
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}
.div-1:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:100px solid #fff;
    border-top:0px;
    bottom:-20px;
    left:-20px;
}

.div-2{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:30px;
}
.div-2:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:100px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:0px;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this still have a problem. My design is responsive and using borders cannot achieve a sloped edge with 100% width. Is there a way to change the 100px for `border-right` and `border-left` so it becomes responsive?

Comment: I'm afraid not! In this instance its the only viable solution, you can always use the skew property, but it will mess with the content of the DIV.